# Build error on Jenkins calling F# compiler with --targetprofile parameter

Tags: jenkins, f#

We are building an Azure solution on Jenkins. This contains several F# projects, a Azure Cloud deployment project, and a C# Azure worker role.

On developer boxes it builds fine.  When building on Jenkins we get:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\REDACTED.sln" (Clean;Build target) (1) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\REDACTED QA\workspace\REDACTED\REDACTED.csproj" (default target) (5:4) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\REDACTED QA\workspace\REDACTED.FSharp.AWS.S3\REDACTED.FSharp.AWS.S3.fsproj" (default target) (6:6) ->
(CoreCompile target) -> 
  FSC : error FS1052: Invalid value 'Qa' for '--targetprofile', valid values are 'mscorlib' or 'netcore'. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\REDACTED QA\workspace\REDACTED.FSharp.AWS.S3\REDACTED.FSharp.AWS.S3.fsproj]
```

The problem seems to be something to do with an MSBuild parameter called 'TargetProfile' we need for the Azure aspects to specify which configuration to use (e.g. UAT or QA) and an undocumented F# parameter called --targetprofile which expects the values mscorlib or netcore.

We'd probably like a workaround which decouples these two usages of 'targetprofile'.  Ideally we'd like not to have to fiddle with things like F#'s targets file as obviously we'd have to remember to apply this in all the places we might build now and in the future.

Comment: I should probably also say that we are using VS 2013 and F# 3.1

Comment: Had a look through the F# compiler source.  Unless I'm mistaken the --targetprofile parameter doesn't even do anything. ;-(

Comment: `--targetprofile` maps to the `primaryAssembly` setting that is [threaded through the compilation](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=primaryAssembly). It allows the compiler to differentiate between "desktop" compiles where mscorlib.dll is the primary framework assembly, and "portable" compiles which instead rely on System.Runtime.dll and various others.  This is needed, e.g., to know where types like System.Object and so on are defined.

Answer (score 2):

Blah, collision between MSBuild property names.

Maybe you can work around by defining a target in your project that runs directly *before* the F# compile target, and sets the F# `TargetProfile` to `mscorlib`, then also define a target that runs directly *after* F# compile that swaps the value back to whatever it was before.

From a quick test this seems to work ok.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- assume TP has Azure-specific value -->
    <TargetProfile>QA</TargetProfile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="BeforeFSharpCompile" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <TempTargetProfile>$(TargetProfile)</TempTargetProfile>
      <TargetProfile>mscorlib</TargetProfile>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="Swapped from $(TempTargetProfile) to $(TargetProfile)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="AfterFSharpCompile" AfterTargets="CoreCompile">
    <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetProfile>$(TempTargetProfile)</TargetProfile>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="Swapped back to $(TargetProfile)" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  We'll give that a try and mark as answer if appropriate.